# Blender 2.81 and Manuel Bastioni Lab : Mask in sculpt mode not visible

Tags: masking, sculpt-mode, manuel-bastioni-lab

I have created a simple character in Mb-Lab without finalising the character yet.
I wanted to make some adjustments in sculpt mode on the eyelids. Because the eyeball is always transforming together with the eyelid I wanted to mask the eyeball.
I found the option to apply the mask and used it to mask the eyeball.
The masks seems to be there ( as the eyeball and part of the eyelids are not moving anymore) but I cannot see the mask.

I already checked for modifier that could hide the mask and deactivated them. I also checked if the viewport option for mask in sculpt mode was on an on 100 % visibility.
Still the mask is invisible and I need to make some adjustments to the mask to properly isolate the eyelids.

Answer (score 1):

The problem were the modifiers that were automatically added by MB-Lab.
While only one modifier showes the warning that the mask will not be displayed all four modifiers

- mbastlab_armature
- mbastlab_corrective_modifier
- mbastlab_subdvision
- mbastlab_displacement

have to be disabled to display the mask correctly in scultp mode.